# GAS Web Application not updating when expected

Tags: google-apps-script

Simple web app. Click button, display three random tasks for today.

The task retrieval backend script takes about 10 seconds to run so I want it to clear the task box while it is doing so so that I know the script fired without opening the console.

This script won't actually clear the text in the tasks box (line 3). The console log "button clicked" fires but the webapp doesn't visually update until the success handler. Is there any way to force a visual update?

```
<script>
  function clickOnButton(){
    document.getElementById('tasks').innerHTML=""; //this doesn't happen when I click the button
    console.log("Button clicked");
    

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        let lines = result.split("\n");
        result = lines.join("<br/>");
        document.getElementById('tasks').innerHTML=result;//this works fine
        })
      .chooseThreeRandom();
    }
  
    

</script>
```

The update after the script returns works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

gs:

```
function chooseThreeRandom() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hs,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const o = [0,1,2].map(idx => vs[Math.floor(Math.random() * vs.length -1)]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  return o;
}

function launchmydialog01() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'),"My Dialog")
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tasks">
    <ul>
      <li>task1</li>
      <li>task2</li>
      <li>task3</li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="DoIt" onClick="doit();" >
  <script>
  function doit(){
    document.getElementById('tasks').innerHTML="";
    console.log("Button clicked");
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(obj => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
        let html = '<ul>';
        obj.forEach(r => {
          html += `<li>${r.join(' ')}</li>`;
        })
        html+='</ul>';
        document.getElementById('tasks').innerHTML=html;
        })
      .chooseThreeRandom();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sheet0:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 |
| 6 | A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 |
| 7 | A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 |
| 8 | A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 |
| 9 | A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 |
| 10 | A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 |
| 11 | A11 | B11 | C11 | D11 | E11 |
| 12 | A12 | B12 | C12 | D12 | E12 |
| 13 | A13 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 |
| 14 | A14 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 |
| 15 | A15 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 |
| 16 | A16 | B16 | C16 | D16 | E16 |
| 17 | A17 | B17 | C17 | D17 | E17 |
| 18 | A18 | B18 | C18 | D18 | E18 |
| 19 | A19 | B19 | C19 | D19 | E19 |
| 20 | A20 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 |
| 21 | A21 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 |
| 22 | A22 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 |
| 23 | A23 | B23 | C23 | D23 | E23 |
| 24 | A24 | B24 | C24 | D24 | E24 |
| 25 | A25 | B25 | C25 | D25 | E25 |
| 26 | A26 | B26 | C26 | D26 | E26 |
| 27 | A27 | B27 | C27 | D27 | E27 |
| 28 | A28 | B28 | C28 | D28 | E28 |
| 29 | A29 | B29 | C29 | D29 | E29 |
| 30 | A30 | B30 | C30 | D30 | E30 |
| 31 | A31 | B31 | C31 | D31 | E31 |
| 32 | A32 | B32 | C32 | D32 | E32 |
| 33 | A33 | B33 | C33 | D33 | E33 |
| 34 | A34 | B34 | C34 | D34 | E34 |
| 35 | A35 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 |
| 36 | A36 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 |
| 37 | A37 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 |
| 38 | A38 | B38 | C38 | D38 | E38 |
| 39 | A39 | B39 | C39 | D39 | E39 |
| 40 | A40 | B40 | C40 | D40 | E40 |
| 41 | A41 | B41 | C41 | D41 | E41 |

Starting Dialog:

[image]

Ending Dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to split it into two functions and it works just fine.

```
<script>
  function clickOnButton(){
    document.getElementById('tasks').innerHTML="testing";
    console.log("Button clicked");
    updateTasks();
    


    }
  function updateTasks(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        let lines = result.split("\n");
        result = lines.join("<br/>");
        document.getElementById('tasks').innerHTML=result;
        })
      .chooseThreeRandom();

  }
  
    

</script>
```